# php file_get_contents() is not working for popup window

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download this webpage http://www.realtor.com/search/searchresults.aspx?mlslid=120012971&source=web using php file_get_contents or curl .I am using this code .

```
<?php

function get_contents($url) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    ob_start();
    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return ob_get_clean();  
}

$url = "http://www.realtor.com/search/searchresults.aspx?mlslid=120012971&source=web";

//$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = get_contents($url);

echo $html;
?>
```

two days ago both process was working well . but there is a popup window now which is creating problem to download this page.Is there any way to bypass the popup window to download the original webpage ??

Comment: FYI, I believe what you are doing here violates Realtor.com's terms of use. Not to mention, scraping will always end up breaking when they change the markup. You may be better off using a real estate api such as offered by trulia or zillow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like access to the webpage required interaction with the webpage. To script multi-action interactive web experiences you need to use an automation tool such as Selenium. Using that suite you can script interactions with DOM and JavaScript-based applications

Comment: how can i use selenium for this particular case ??

Comment: That's a completely different question.